# Getting biography summary from lastfm: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

Im getting the top artists from a specify country using last fm api and I want to save the name, url and the biograpgy for each top artist. The name and url is working fine, but the biography is not working.

Im doing like this to get the name and url of the top artists:

```
import requests

api_key = "" 
ID = 0
artists = {}

for i in range(1, 3):
    artists_response = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&format=json&page=' + str(i) + '&api_key=' + api_key)
    artists_data = artists_response.json()

    #print(artists_data)

    for artist in artists_data["topartists"]["artist"]:
        name = artist["name"]
        url = artist["url"]


        image = artist["image"]

        artists[ID] = {}
        artists[ID]['ID'] = ID
        artists[ID]['name'] = name
        artists[ID]['url'] = url
        artists[ID]['image'] = image
        ID += 1


#print(artists)
```

At this point is working fine. But now I want to get the biography summary for each topartist, but it is appearing the error "TypeError: string indices must be integers", on " `print(artist["summary"])`":

```
for i,v in artists.items():
    chosen = artists[i]['name'].replace(" ", "+")
    artist_response = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&format=json&artist='+chosen+'&api_key='+api_key)
    artist_data = artist_response.json()

    #print(artist_data)

    for artist in artist_data['artist']['bio']:
       print(artist["summary"])
       bio = artist["summary"]
       artists[ID]['bio'] = bio

   # print(artist_response)
```

Comment: that's because `artist` is a string not a dict.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But so do you know why in this part "for artist in artists_data["topartists"]["artist"]:" works fine?

Comment: because in that case it's probably a dictionary.

Comment: But the responses have both the same format.

Comment: It might help to see what at least some of the relevant contents of `artist_data` is.

Comment: Example: {"artist":{"name":"U2","mbid":"a3cb23fc-acd3-4ce0-8f36-1e5aa6a18432",

"url":"https://www.last.fm/music/U2"},"bio":{"links":{"link":{"#text":"","rel":"original","href":"https://last.fm/music/U2/+wiki"}},"summary":"U2 is an alternative rock band..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example data, it is clear that `artist_data["artist"]["bio"]` is a dictionary, so that the loop assigns the *keys* of that dictionary (which are strings) to `artist`.

As you have not provided an example of `artist_data["top_artists"]`, I cannot speak to why that did not produce the same error.

Comment: Thanks. The artist_data["top_artist"] exemple: {'topartists': {'name': 'U2', 'listeners': '3390992', 'mbid': 'a3cb23fc-acd3-4ce0-8f36-1e5aa6a18432', 'url': 'https://www.last.fm/music/U2', ...

Comment: And `artists_data["topartists"]["artist"]`?

Comment: This: {'name': 'U2', 'listeners': '3390992', 'mbid': 'a3cb23fc-acd3-4ce0-8f36-1e5aa6a18432', 'url': 'https://www.last.fm/music/U2', 'streamable': '0', 'image': [{'#text'...